# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}S(x)$

Tags: calculus

Let the function $S(x)$ be a sum, such that $S(x)=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n)^2$ and $|x|<1$. Question is, does $\lim_{x \to 0}S(x)=0$? This is the equivalent of taking the limit of the infinite sum. Since we know that $|x|<1$, the infinite sum can only be decreasing. As $n$ increases. However, this does not mean that the limit is 0. In fact, it should be a positive number. So I think the limit equation is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the infinite sum. $1+x+x^2 ...$ is a GP with common ratio $x$... So infinite sum is $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ and lim $x$ goes to zero $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ is one.

1.